# How to Highlight a 3D Surface Plot slice

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy, matplotlib-3d

I was wondering how to highlight a 3D surface plot (done by SymPy Plotting Backends) with the help of matplotlib (because I find an example here: [How do I highlight a slice on a matplotlib 3D surface plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483209/how-do-i-highlight-a-slice-on-a-matplotlib-3d-surface-plot))
it is using matplotlib.

To create the surface 3D plot is done by SPB (with backend=MB) with this code:

```
from sympy import *
from spb import * # pip install sympy_plot_backends
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
init_printing()

var("t, omega, s, alpha")
expr = exp(-t) * sin(t)
res = laplace_transform(expr, t, s, noconds=True)
print(res)

colorscale = [
    [0, "green"],
    [0.01, "orange"],
    [0.05, "red"],
    [1, "red"]
]
print('The Laplace Transform plot in 3-D:')
plot3d(abs(res.subs(s, alpha + I * omega)), (alpha, -2, 2), (omega, -2, 2), 
    use_cm=True, colorbar=False, backend=MB)
print('The slice highlighted plot:')
#Z = abs(res.subs(s, alpha + I * omega))
#y0 = 10
#C[y0] = plt.cm.Reds_r(Z[y0]/2)
#plt.figure(figsize = (15,15))
#plt.plot((alpha, -2, 2), (omega, -2, 2),Z[y0,:], color=plt.cm.Reds(.7))
#plt.show()
```

I comment out my trial, it does not work as I want it to, this is the slice should look like from one side of alpha axis:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plotting a slice as suggested on that question is difficult to achieve with SPB. Instead, we are going to do achieve it in a different way.

First, plot the surface:

```py
from sympy import *
from spb import *
var("t, omega, s, alpha")
expr = exp(-t) * sin(t) #* exp(-t / 2)
res = laplace_transform(expr, t, s, noconds=True)
func = abs(res.subs(s, alpha + I*omega))

p1 = plot3d(
    func, (alpha, -2, 2), (omega, -2, 2), {"cmap": "winter", "vmax": 2},
    zlim=(0, 2.5), use_cm=True, colorbar=False
)
```

[image]

Next, plot the slice, which is nothing more than a parametric curve in 3D space. For example, plotting a slice at `alpha=-0.5`:

```py
p2 = plot3d_parametric_line((-0.5, omega, func.subs(alpha, -0.5)), (omega, -2, 2), {"color": "r"}, use_cm=False)
```

[image]

Finally, combine the plots:

```py
(p1 + p2).show()
```

[image]

Here you see the limitations of Matplotlib: it doesn't know that the line should be rendered on top of the surface. This problem doesn't exist in Plotly, which is why I suggested that backend in a previous question.

To solve this problem with Matplotlib, we can plot 2 surfaces:

- one surface goes from `alpha=-2` to `alpha=-0.5-eps`, with `eps` a small number.
- another surface goes from `alpha=-0.5+eps` to `alpha=2`.

We apply the same colormap to both surfaces.

```py
eps = 0.01
p1 = plot3d(
    (func, (alpha, -2, -0.5-eps), (omega, -2, 2), {"cmap": "winter", "vmax": 2}),
    (func, (alpha, -0.5+eps, 2), (omega, -2, 2), {"cmap": "winter", "vmax": 2}),
    zlim=(0, 2.5), use_cm=True, colorbar=False
)
```

[image]

Then, you combine it with the slice:

```py
(p1 + p2).show()
```

[image]

Comment: Genius way, we cut a line of a surface, `matplotlib` is not giving limitation, it gives you more idea and creativity then. Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: Following this approach, you can also create stripes at a given location, just replace the parametric line with another surface, closing the gap between the other two surfaces :)